# How to add database in controller to app Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

I have a Yii2 project and this app should transfer data between many databases and should connect to them at the same time.

The problem is the proper database is sent from the user (is in user's request) and  I don't want to connect to all the databases at the beginning of the app, Because of two reasons:

1. Database numbers are enormous
2. In some requests, connecting to one db is enough and connecting to all of them is useless and may affect the process speed.

So I should create a DB connection in the controller. I can't create connection in `raw php` because I want to pass the connection to some of my models and my models should transfer data with new Database.

In the other words, I want to create instances from one model but with multiple databases.

I have tried to add db to my project like this but it throws `can not add property to Component or App`.

These are my codes that didn't work:

```
 Yii::$app->db2 = [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databasename',
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

and

```
 Yii::$app->components->db2 = [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databasename',
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

Comment: You would need create configuration in config/web.php for each database connection. In respective models you would need use function     public static function getDb() {
        return Yii::$app->get('myNewDB');
    }

Answer (score 3):

To access a database, you could also build a db connect without using application component in this  case you first need to connect to the db  by creating an instance of `yii\db\Connection:

```
  $yourdb = new yii\db\Connection([
      'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=example',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => '',
      'charset' => 'utf8',
  ]);
```

the you can  access to the db eg:

```
$posts = $db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM post')->queryAll();
```

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-dao#creating-db-connections

Comment: How can I pass this connection to public static function getDb of my model?

Comment: you could redefine the related  getDb .. and pass  the value you need ..  just add  a getDb to your model  ..  that work as you need  .. you coudld store the connect in a global param and retrive the related  value in getDb ... there are several way  ..

Comment: Can I have two instances of a single model that are connected to two different databases?

Comment: this seems a new question to  ,, me  .. and is not clear what your are looking for ..  .. anyway .. you should manage two different connection (eg: getDb1 and getDb2) for accessing the db you need  each time   but the model can work with several DB  .. the db tables  related  must have the same struct /schema

Answer (score 0):

In your config file, will depend what template you are using, for basic template in `config/db.php`, advanced template will be `/common/config/main-local.php`. Create two arrays for each of the db's inside components like:

```
'components' => [
    'db1' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db',
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'pass',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
    'db2' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=whateveritscalled;dbname=db2',
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'pass',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
 ]
];
```

Then you should be able to access them like:

```
Yii::$app->db1->createCommand()

Yii::$app->db2->createCommand()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`Application::set()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-di-servicelocator#set()-detail) to configure component in this way:

```
Yii::app->set('db2', [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databasename',
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
]);

Yii::$app->db2->createCommand($sql)->execute();
```

Also note that Yii uses lazy loading for initiating components. Even if you configure DB connection component, this component will not be initialized and connection will not be opened as long as you don't use it. So you can safely configure 1000 DB components (`db1, db2, ... db1000`), and use only one - other 999 components will not initialized and only one DB connection will be opened.

However if you have such big number of databases, you may consider creating some kind of `DbManager` which will store all available connections configuration and initialize connection on request (like `Yii::$app->dbManager->get('123'); // <- returns connection nr 123`) - it should be more clean than registering additional thousand of components and definitely more clean than setting DB connection component in controller.